# How to add custom module data to Customer Order detail page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

I am new in Magento. I want to add custom data (**That I have created a custom module for that, Which generates a code like a Product SKU.**).

So that code should be seen on Customer's ***Order view page -> Items Orders tab***.
At Just below to Product name(See screenshot).
I have used magento 2.4.3

I have mentioned in the screenshot "Text here".

[image]

Please suggest in detail.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have override order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml.** from below path

```
\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\order\items\renderer\default.phtml
```

In order to override the default.phtml file create **sales_order_item_renderers.xml** file in the **app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/layout/ folder** and copy the following code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.items.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" name="sales.order.items.renderer.default.simple" as="simple" template="Vendor_Modulename::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

copy file **default.phtml** and put at module

```
app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/templates/order/view/items/renderer/renderer/default.phtml
```

update code with default.phtml

I have done / Fixed from @Gohil Rajesh's answer that was for admin. So I have done it at the frontend (See screenshot).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**You need to override order/items/renderer/default.phtml.** from below path

```
\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\view\items\renderer\default.phtml
```

In order to override the default.phtml file, we need to first create sales_order_item_renderers.xml file in the app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/layout/ folder and copy the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.items.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer"
                   name="sales.order.items.renderer.default.configurable" as="configurable"
                   template="Namespace_Module::order/items/renderer/default.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer"
                   name="sales.order.items.renderer.default.simple" as="simple"
                   template="MageDelight_Training::order/items/renderer/default.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Downloadable\Block\Sales\Order\Item\Renderer\Downloadable"
                   name="sales.order.items.renderer.downloadable" as="downloadable"
                   template="Namespace_Module::order/items/renderer/default.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Bundle\Block\Sales\Order\Items\Renderer"
                   name="sales.order.items.renderers.bundle" as="bundle"
                   template="Namespace_Module::order/items/renderer/bundle/renderer.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\Grouped"
                   name="sales.order.items.renderers.grouped" as="grouped"
                   template="Namespace_Module::order/items/renderer/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

please copy file **default.phtml** and put in your module

```
app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/items/renderer/bundle/renderer/default.phtml
```

now add your code as per your need in default.phtml

Comment: Hello Gohil, Let me try this way.
update here soon.

Comment: But it looks like code for the backend (admin sales order).
but it's helpful for me to get direction. Thank you for that.

So, I am giving the correct solution by posting the answer.

Comment: Opps.. I thought You are looking for admin order

Comment: glad to hear. finally you found it